# Неправильная отрисовка линейного графика в matplotlib. Несоответствие угла прямой и рассчитанного коэффициента

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Программа должна принимать координаты точек (x,y), по которым строится линия. То есть сначала рассчитывается коэффициент угла наклона (k) методом парных точек. Затем для каждой точки считаю значение свободного члена (b), суммирую все свободные члены и произвожу деление на количество пар - получаю (sb) среднее значение.

уравнение прямой: y=kx+b

На входе: рациональные числа (x,y)

Пример ввода данных:

30 53 75 86 150 201

2 5 7 13 22 32

32,7656 43,654 45 656

34,56 39 44,6 666,6

На выходе: график, коэффициент, среднее отклонение прямой от точек, погрешность коэффициента

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import array

print("Программа для построения графика\n")
x=[]
y=[]


while True:
    print("Введите координаты точек X через пробел")
    x=input().replace(',','.').split()
    print("Введите координаты точек Y через пробел")
    y=input().replace(',','.').split()
    if ((len(y)==len(x))) and (not(len(x)<=3 or len(y)<=3)): 
        break
    elif (len(y)!=len(x)):
        prinnt("y и x должно совпадать!")
    else:
        print("\n!!!нужно больше координат!!!")
print ('x:',x)
print ('y:',y)
try:
    k1=(float(y[-3])-float(y[0]))/(float(x[-3])-float(x[0]))
    k2=(float(y[-2])-float(y[1]))/(float(x[-2])-float(x[1]))
    k3=(float(y[-1])-float(y[2]))/(float(x[-1])-float(x[2]))
    print("\n k1= ",k1,"\n k2= ",k2,"\n k3= ",k3,"\n")
    k=(k1+k2+k3)/3
    q=math.sqrt((((k1-k)*(k2-k)*(k3-k))**2)/6)
    print('\nУгол наклона прямой: k=',k,'\nПогрешность коэффициента: q=',q)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("что-то делится на ноль")


sb=0
sq=0
lq=array.array('d', [0]) * len(x)
b=array.array('d', [0]) * len(x)

for i in range(len(x)):
    b[i]=float(y[i])-float(k)*float(x[i])
    sb+=b[i]
sb=sb/len(x)
for i in range (len(x)):
    lq[i]=((1/math.sqrt(1+k*k))*(k*float(x[i])-float(y[i])+sb))
    sq+=lq[i]
sq=sq/len(x)
print("свободный член b: ",sb)
print("подсчитанное среднее отклонение прямой от точек: ",sq)



plt.title("график")
plt.xlabel("ось X")
plt.ylabel("ось Y")
plt.plot([1, 1*k+sb])
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i],y[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: можете привести примеры ввода пользователя?

Answer (score 4):

Сначала вы рисуете прямую с коэффициентом `1` (угол наклона 45 градусов):

```
In [158]: print(f"({1}, {1*k+sb})")
(1, 1.728514810003242)

In [159]: plt.plot([1, 1*k+sb])
Out[159]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xd874828>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после этого рисуете точки, представленные в вид **строк**:

```
In [153]: x
Out[153]: ['1.1', '8.8', '3.75', '12.1']

In [154]: y
Out[154]: ['0.123', '5.67', '4.1', '7.12']
```

по смыслу это тоже самое что чертить следующие "точки":

```
In [155]: plt.scatter(['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','g','h'])
Out[155]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0xdc4dcc0>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно пользоваться функциями [plt.scatter()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), [plt.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)?

Обе функции ожидают **массив** `X` координат в качестве первого аргумента и массив `Y` координат в качестве второго аргумента.

Пример:

```
In [195]: str_x = '30 53 75 86 150 201'

In [196]: str_y = '2 5 7 13 22 32'

In [197]: x = np.array(str_x.split()).astype('int')

In [198]: y = np.array(str_y.split()).astype('int')

In [199]: x
Out[199]: array([ 30,  53,  75,  86, 150, 201])

In [200]: y
Out[200]: array([ 2,  5,  7, 13, 22, 32])

In [201]: plt.scatter(x, y)
Out[201]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x12d6db45400>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтобы правильно найти прямую линейной интерполяции, можно воспользоваться линейной регрессией:

```
In [202]: from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

In [203]: lr = LinearRegression()

In [204]: lr.fit(x.reshape(-1,1), y)
Out[204]:
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None,
         normalize=False)

In [205]: lr.coef_
Out[205]: array([0.17780238])

In [206]: lr.intercept_
Out[206]: -4.13206906860805
```

график:

```
In [207]: plt.plot(x, x*lr.coef_ + lr.intercept_, color='r')
Out[207]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12d6c2f0b70>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]